# Select records from a List with a specific RecordTypeId

Tags: query, list, record

I have a List of the object Animal, with records from two different record types,

How can I return another List with the animals with one of those record types?? 
Preferrably using a query instead of a loop but I accept a solution with loops

A lot of thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to iterate over the List?

Comment: I do not want to waste resources but I accept that solution also I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method in the provided [List class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) that will do this. Iterating over a list is not very resource intensive, and will be faster than re-querying. A quick method like this should do the trick:

```
private List<Animal__c> animalListByRT (List<Animal__c> animals, Id recordTypeId) {
    List<Animal__c> animalList = new List<Animal__c>();
    for (Animal__c a : animals) {
        if (a.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId) {
            animalList.add(a);
        }
    }
    return animalList;
}
```

You can also look at your original query and see if grouping or sorting by RecordType would be possible, and that could be a way to get sub-lists by RecordType more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

may be

List animals = [Select Id, RecordType.Name from Animal__c where RecordTypeId = 'YOUR_ANIMAL_RECORD_TYPE_ID']